# ASP.NET MVC C# dynamic radiobuttons getting formcollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have a form in which there can be multiple radio buttons generated dynamically in the view ,on the form submitted how can i collect the values in the controller. For example there are radio buttons dynamically generated like Gender (Male and Female), Education  (BS,MS,BCS) . how can i have there value in the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the names of the radio buttons you could use action parameters. If the names are arbitrary you could fetch the values from a [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection.aspx) parameter passed to your POST action (it is a `NameValueCollection` so you could loop through the key and get the corresponding values).

Personally I would recommend you using deterministic names:

```
Gender:
<input type="radio" value="M" name="radios[0]" />
<input type="radio" value="F" name="radios[0]" />

Education:
<input type="radio" value="BS" name="radios[1]" />
<input type="radio" value="MS" name="radios[1]" />
<input type="radio" value="BCS" name="radios[1]" />
```

And in your controller action you could use a collection:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(string[] radios)
{
    // The radios collection will contain the selected values like:
    // radios[0] = "F"
    // radios[1] = "MS"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way would be to use form collections if they are dynamically generated radio buttons.

```
public ActionResult controllername(FormCollection form)
{
     foreach(string radioName in dynamicRadioList)
     {
           var value = form[radioName];
           //blah blah
     }
}
```