# ASP.NET MVC 3 getting values from dynamic radiobuttons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I have a VERY similar question to this question:

[ASP.NET MVC C# dynamic radiobuttons getting formcollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409740/asp-net-mvc-c-dynamic-radiobuttons-getting-formcollection)

However, the only difference is, instead of naming the names as:

name="radios[0]" and name="radios[1]", with an 0 and 1, respectively, I need to start mine at 1.

When it comes into public ActionResult Update(string[] radios), it is null because it does not start at 0.  I am trying to get this to work using a Dictionary<int, int> radios, and having my names as:

name="radios[1][1 through 3]" and then name="radios[2][1 through 3]" but it doesn't seem to  be working.  Any ideas?  I can not just subtract 1 from all the values because that's not necessarily the case, I said I am using 1 as an example.  Thanks, any help would be great!!

Comment: Are the radio buttons part of a single group or are there multiple groups of radio buttons?

Comment: for the sake of this question, there are two groups of radio buttons, each with a particular ID.  So I basically want to find out the IDs of the group, and also the selected value of both groups through one parameter in my action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at phil haacked [blog entry](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx), specifically the part: Non-Sequential Indices

To summerise, you need to add 3 new hidden fields, all called radios.Index, one with the value 1 , one with value 2 and the other with the value of 3

e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="radios.Index" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="radios.Index" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="radios.Index" value="3" />
```

Martin